# Как убрать работу кнопок без fn?

Tags: windows, hotkeys

На моем ноутбуке клавиши f1 f2 f3 и тд, имеют доп функции переход в режим сна, отключение wi-fi и тд, но они срабатывают при простом нажатии на кнопку, а сам кнопка работает только с fn, а должно быть все наоборот, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Это зависит от ноутбука, и windows тут ни при чём. Обращайтесь к инструкции вашего ноутбука

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего ищите в биосе, примерно так.
Нажмите клавишу `f10`(или другую, в зависимости от ноутбука), чтобы открыть окно установок BIOS.
Перейдите в меню System Configuration (Конфигурация системы) с помощью клавиш со стрелками влево/вправо.
Окно настройки BIOS с выбранными параметрами System Configuration (Конфигурация системы) и Action Keys Mode (Режим функциональных клавиш)
Disabled (отключено): Требует нажатия и удерживания функциональной клавиши (fn) при одновременном нажатии одной из клавиш с f1 по f12 для использования функции, указанной на данной клавише.
Если такого нет то стоит уточнить что у вас за ноутбук

Comment: `f10` - это у HP. У большинства - `del` и `f2`. Но есть ещё Lenovo и Sony Vaio, у которых вообще отдельная кнопка для входа в БИОС.

Comment: @donRumata ну это да, но думаю автор вопроса разберется как зайти в биос на своем ноутбуке, суть же вопроса не в этом. А так поправил ответ